# What is that delay when I try to create a "Folder" inside a "Folder Group" in Outlook O365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

The hierarchy (and I use that term loosely) in `Notes` or in `Tasks` I can make a new `Folder` under a `Folder Group`.

But everytime I do this it seems like it take a while for it to appear, or I have to actually add something to it for it to appear after I create it...or there's a delay before it shows up.

What causes this?  Is this a "feature" or is it just a connection delay?

Comment: Also, what the heck is a Folder Group?  To me it sounds like the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

What's your account type? Exchange, POP or IMAP?

What do you mean by "Folder Group"?

Do you right click “Task” or “Note” folder and then choose “New Folder…”?
When testing on my Outlook, it will appear immediately. You can recreate the OST file to see if it helps.

Reference:   [Repair Outlook Data Files (.pst and .ost)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253)

Besides, we can run /resetnavpane to clears and regenerates the Navigation Pane for the current profile. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type “outlook /resetnavpane” and then press Enter.

Comment: When you right click the large text that says `My Notes` the context menu says `New Folder Group` and if you click it, you get another large text on the sidebar just like the `My Notes` one, so I assume this is called a `Folder Group`

Comment: It's `Exchange` hosted with O365

Comment: Does this issue only occur when creating folders under custom Folder group ?

Comment: No it's in the default one.  I have a custom one too though.  I made it by mistake.

Comment: This is strange. We may also create a new profile in case it was related with personal settings.